# Qt how to create a settings/configuration window

Tags: c++, windows-7, qt4

I was trying to find an example of creating a settings/configuration windows. The settings window is launched by clicking "Options" action in the menu item. I wanted to figure out how to open up a 2nd window from the main window. As well how the new window return the settings information back to main window. Tried to play around with the QDialog or some inherited dialog classes, but those are for limited uses, not for general setting window. Is there any example/documentation about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this property browser. Similar to property editor in Qt Designer. [qtpropertybrowser](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/qt-solutions/source/fd22bee22274975c56f1c10d87ee9fd2c0818f83%3aqtpropertybrowser) [Image](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq18-propertybrowser-widgets.png)